# Why does Euclid's algorithm taken one step past the GCD seem to yield the LCM?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, divisibility

In class we are going over Euclid's Algorithm.  For example, we learned that for integers $m$, $n$:$$\gcd(m,n) = sm + tn$$
Where $s$ and $t$ are integers that can be plugged in to satisfy the equation.

We also learned to step through the recursive algorithm like so:
$$\gcd(m, n) = \gcd(m, n \bmod m)$$
to get pairs of coefficients $s$ and $t$ until we reached a remainder of zero ($n \bmod m = 0$), meaning the $s$ and $t$ at that point in the recursion are the ones that yield:$$sm + tn = \gcd(m,n)$$

What we observed but couldn't explain (professor included) was that if you take the algorithm one step further, getting $s'$ and $t'$ such that $s'm + t'n = 0$, it seems to be always true that $s'm = \operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

To clarify, I understand that the algorithm can't divide by zero, but if you continue the pattern:
$$s'' = s - s'*q$$
$$t'' = t - t'*q$$
you get an $s''$ and $t''$ such that:
$$s''*m + t''*n = 0$$
Then taking this $s''$, multiplying it by the original $m$, you see that this is the $lcm(m, n)$. This seems to be true consistently, but I haven't been able to find a counterproof, contradiction, counterexample, etc, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to disprove it, or if there was a proof to verify this was always the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the algorithm one step further"? The algorithm can't be taken one step further, without dividing by zero.

Comment: This is evidently not true: $1000\cdot2-500\cdot 4=0$, but $2000$ is of course not the lowest common multiple of $2$ and $4$. It's trivial to see that $s'm$ is a common multiple of $m$ and $n$, though.

Comment: @egreg yes, it is trivial to see, but not trivial to prove.  I am trying to determine what the proof is, to see if it is true in all cases.

Comment: If $s'm=-t'n$, then *obviously* $s'm$ is a common multiple of $m$ and $n$. But quite certainly *not* the least common multiple, unless you choose the *minimal* positive $s'$ (which is $n/\gcd(m,n)$), assuming $m\ne0$ and $n\ne0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand that the algorithm can't divide by zero, but if you continue the pattern s'' = s - s'*q, t'' = t - t'*q, you get an s and t such that s*m + t*n = zero.  Then taking this s, multiplying it by m, you see that this is the LCM of m and n.  This seems to be true consistently, I haven't been able to find a counterproof, contradiction, counterexample, etc, so I was wondering if anyone knew how to disprove it, or if there was a proof to verify this was always the case.

Comment: @egreg I agree, I discovered this in a homework assignment last night.  But if you continue the pattern s'' = s - s'*q, t'' = t - t'*q, you *do* get an s and t such that s*m + t*n = zero and also such that s'*m *is* the LCM of m and n.  It's consistent but I haven't been able to find a proof or counterproof for it in a couple of days now so I'm not confident in it.

Comment: @fts_acer You're essentially proving that $mn=\gcd(m,n)\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: @egreg I've done that proof before, can't remember it by heart but it has to do with taking m*(n/gcd) * n*(m/gcd) and going from there.  But how does this all relate to the (s*m + t*n = zero) bit?  I am having a hard time seeing the connection.

Comment: I'm glad you have explained what you meant by taking the algorithm one step further. Now please edit that explanation into the body of the question, so no one has to search through the comments to understand what the question is asking.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson, I'm new here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be two positive integers.
Euclid's algorithm produces unique sequences $(r_n),(s_n),(t_n)$ such that :

- $r_0=a$, $r_1=b$ and $r_{n+1} = r_{n-1} - q_n r_n$ (with usual conditions on $(r_{n+1},q_n)$).
- $s_0=1$, $s_1=0$, $t_0=1$, $t_1=1$ and $s_{n+1} = s_{n-1} - q_n s_n$, $t_{n+1} = t_{n-1} - q_n t_n$. This implies $r_n = s_n a_n + t_n b_n$.

Let $r_N$ be the last remainder. Then $r_N = s_N a + t_N b$ is Bezout's relation for $\gcd(a,b)$, and $0 = r_{N+1} = s_{N+1} a + t_{N+1} b$.

You are asking why $|r_{N+1} a| = |t_{N+1} b|$ is equal to ${\rm lcm}(a,b)$.
Note that the sequence $w_n := s_{n} r_{n+1} - s_{n+1} r_{n}$ is constant and so $w_N=w_0$. But
$$w_N = s_{N+1} r_N = s_{N+1}.\gcd(a,b)$$
and
$$w_0 = b.$$
Combining with the fact that $\gcd(a,b).{\rm lcm}(a,b)=ab$, this implies $s_{N+1} a = {\rm lcm}(a,b)$.

Comment: You definitely understood and clarified my question well!  But I could not understand the steps taken to come to the answer. Where you wrote |rN+1a| did you mean |sN+1a|?  Also, why is (s(n)r(n+1))−s(n+1)r(n)) constant?

Comment: Your are right there is a typo.
About $w_n$, just compute $w_{n+1}$ with the induction formula (and in fact it is $(-1)^n w_n$ which is constant).

Comment: I suspect your answer is right since you understood what I was asking, but I don't understand the last two lines, in other words I don't understand why $$w_0 = b.$$ or why $$s_{N+1} a = {\rm lcm}(a,b)$$ is implied.

Comment: $w_n$ is defined to be $s_nr_{n+1}-s_{n+1}r_n$, so $w_0=s_0r_1-s_1r_0$. But $r_0=a$, $r_1=b$, $s_0=1$, $s_1=0$, so $w_0=b$.